# Is it possible to change the family_guid in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a bit of a problem with some databases I'm trying to migrate to amazon RDS

We have about 20 Databases that are all derivatives of others that all share the same family_guid because they are based on backups of others. The problem is that amazon will not allow you to restore a DB that has the same family_guid of another even if they are two separate databases. This is where my question comes in, Is it possible to change the guid or am I out of luck and will need to do some exports/imports on these databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same scenario as you - many DBs all based off a template, and all need to go into RDS.

AFAIK there is no way to change the underlying family_guid in a simple command.
However, using the .bacpac export/import will assign a new family_guid to the imported DB. Sadly you can't directly import a .bacpac into RDS (the import fails, and you can't delete the database!)

So, as a work around, I ended up with the following process:

1. Create a .bacpac (contains both data & schema) of the original DB.
2. Import that .bacpac into a staging database (could be LocalDB, or another instance somewhere, or even the same instance as the original DB).
3. Create a traditional backup (.bak) of the staging DB.
4. Upload the backup to S3.
5. Run the msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database command on the S3 backup file.

Quite a process for what should be a simple task!

Comment: This seems to be the fastest way of handling this. We were using an SQL import tools but after looking into bacpac that may be a quicker way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Update - Sometime in 2017 or 2018 it became possible import a .bacpac file directly into RDS. Using SQL Server Management Studio you just right-click on the source DB and choose 'Tasks->Export Data-tier Application'. On the target RDS server right click the Databases folder and choose 'Import Data-tier Application'.

Answer (score 0):

The `family_guid` is a unique ID that is generated when a database is created. It remains the same, even when a database is restored.

You generally see the `family_guid` when querying `msdb.dbo.backupset` or using the `RESTORE HEADERONLY` command.

My understanding is that this is a completely static value and cannot be changed.

If you need to "change" it, I'd suggest creating a new database, then exporting/importing. You might try [creating a BACPAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213241.aspx) to export the schema & data, so that you can import it into a new database.