# Is there any way to replace sql server file_guid with new GUID?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, amazon-rds

I have two databases with same file_guid. Getting following error when trying to restore second database in Amazon RDS.

> Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB
>   request. Task ID 8 (RESTORE_DB) exception: Database DATABASENAME
>   cannot be restored because there is already an existing database with
>   the same file_guids on the instance.

This is because I already restored another database with same file_guid but different physical_name), which is an Amazon RDS limitation. If interested find details in [here](http://ramblingsofraju.com/sql-server/aws-sql-server-rds-native-backup-restore/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/category/rds-sql-server/).

[image: Query result on sys.database_files]

How can I update sys.database_files record?

Comment: It seems like Amazon pointed out the work around, put it on a new instance. I know that isn't what you're asking but that's the supported method they seem to have. I would not advise trying to change these values.

Answer (score 7):

We had to do the same - as we wanted to copy a database to a new database, changing the name and file IDs at the same time.

We found the original process posted here to not to be repeatable, I guess it depends on how the original file ids were created.  In any event, I have updated the following procedure, which is repeatable.

1. Backup database from RDS to S3 using standard RDS database backup.

   ```
   exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
   @source_db_name = '<database-name>',
   @s3_arn_to_backup_to = 'arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/<backup-filename>'
   ```
2. Restore .bak file into SQL Server on a local machine.  We have MSDN account, so we just downloaded SQL 2016 and installed, giving us full access to SQL on a local machine.  But, I believe you can download SQL Express and do the same, some functionality may be lost depending on the source version of the SQL Engine.
3. Perform a Export Data Tier Application for the database.  This will create a .bacpac file which includes the schema, data and code (stored procedures, etc.).
4. Delete the original data imported into SQL Server in step 3.
5. Perform an Import Data Tier Application and point to the .bacpac file created in step 3.  This step will set the file guids = _Data and _Logs, making them unique.
6. Do a full backup to get a new .bak file.
7. Upload new .bak file to S3 and do standard RDS database import.

   ```
   exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
   @restore_db_name = '<database-name>',
   @s3_arn_to_restore_from = 'arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/<backup-filename>'
   ```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Upon restore, change destination database name and file IDs"?  I did a restore with "MOVE" and exported again and still get the same error.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the procedure. It worked about 20% of the time on database we were copying to make TEST versions.  See the revised steps - this process has worked on all of the databases we needed to copy in RDS.  As mentioned above, for large databases, data tier export will take forever and will almost seem to be hung.  We had a 2 GB DB that said it was done, but really did not close out for 20 minutes.  If you have really large database, I guess creating a 2nd instance and importing it there is your other option.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have ended up with creating new RDS instance and restore there. There are others work around for small database are  1. Creating .bacpac and import into new database, then take backup (.bak). See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148159/111078). 2. Generate script with both schema and data and run on new database.

.bacpac or generating script ways did not work for me because of bigger database size ( over 10 GB), RDS is cost effective but a pain for DBA.

Answer (score 1):

This no longer appears to be an issue.  I have restored a database to the same server with a different name.  It shares the same file_guid however and both databases are online without issue.  You can use the following query to quickly see the files and locations of the databases on your rds server.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName, name AS LogicalFileName, physical_name AS PhysicalFileName, file_guid AS File_Guid
FROM sys.master_files
```